# SQLite. How to populate ListView partially?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am trying to populate ListView from SQLite database.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE meaning(
key TEXT, 
value TEXT, 
entries BLOB);
```

And created this index for column **key**:

```
CREATE INDEX index_key on meaning(key);
```

I am using this query to get needed data from database:

```
SELECT rowid AS _id, value, entries 
FROM meaning 
WHERE key 
LIKE 'dog%' 
ORDER BY key 
LIMIT 100
```

Result is coming in 510ms. This is quite slow for incremental search. Is it possible to populate ListView part by part so that when user scrolls down ListView, other part of data will be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load the data in parts so that the user sees the result set only as the view is being swiped down. Follow the example at this location http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-infinitely-scrolling-list-android/ to see how it's done.

Basically all you're doing is listening to the scroll change and then adding more results from a loader. Don't forget that once the results have been added to the underlying list, they are not removed simply because you swipe back up. From that point on, they will always be there.